# React Native custom animation slows down the app

Tags: react-native

I was trying to add a pulse animation to a button and followed the code in the plugin https://github.com/sahlhoff/react-native-pulse to build one. The resulting component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  pulse: {
    position: 'absolute',
    flex: 1
  }
});

export default class Pulse extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    style: {
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    color: 'blue',
    numPulses: 3,
    diameter: 400,
    speed: 10,
    duration: 1000
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      started: false,
      style: this.props.style,
      image: this.props.image,
      color: this.props.color,
      numPulses: this.props.numPulses,
      maxDiameter: this.props.diameter,
      speed: this.props.speed,
      duration: this.props.duration,
      pulses: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { numPulses, duration, speed } = this.state;

    this.starter();

    let a = 0;
    while (a < numPulses) {
      this.createPulseTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.createPulse(a);
      }, a * duration);

      a++;
    }

    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.updatePulse();
    }, speed);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
    clearTimeout(this.createPulseTimer);
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  mounted = true;

  createPulse = () => {
    if (this.mounted) {
      const { pulses } = this.state;

      const pulse = {
        pulseKey: pulses.length + 1,
        diameter: 0,
        opacity: 0.5
      };

      pulses.push(pulse);

      this.setState({ pulses });
    }
  };

  starter() {
    this.setState({ started: true });
  }

  updatePulse = () => {
    if (this.mounted) {
      const pulses = this.state.pulses.map((p, i) => {
        const { maxDiameter } = this.state;
        const newDiameter = p.diameter > maxDiameter ? 0 : p.diameter + 2;
        const centerOffset = (maxDiameter - newDiameter) / 2;
        const opacity = Math.abs(newDiameter / this.state.maxDiameter - 1);

        const pulse = {
          pulseKey: i + 1,
          diameter: newDiameter,
          opacity: opacity > 0.5 ? 0.5 : opacity,
          centerOffset
        };

        return pulse;
      });

      this.setState({ pulses });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      style, image, maxDiameter, color, started, pulses
    } = this.state;
    const wrapperStyle = [styles.container, style];
    const containerStyle = { width: maxDiameter, height: maxDiameter };

    return (
      <View style={wrapperStyle}>
        {started && (
          <View style={containerStyle}>
            {pulses.map(pulse => (
              <View
                key={pulse.pulseKey}
                style={[
                  styles.pulse,
                  {
                    backgroundColor: color,
                    width: pulse.diameter,
                    height: pulse.diameter,
                    opacity: pulse.opacity,
                    borderRadius: pulse.diameter / 2,
                    top: pulse.centerOffset,
                    left: pulse.centerOffset
                  }
                ]}
              />
            ))}
            {this.props.children}
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is, this heavily slows down the app. Normally the app runs at about 60fps (Both UI and JS). But when this component is active the JS performance goes down to nearly 35fps. Any idea what's happening? The app is running on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html). It's much faster.
Pulses can be easily created with scale animations.